# What protocol is served from Express applications?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, soap, json-rpc

when I build an server using Node.js's Express, what protocol is used by default? REST? Json-RPC? SOAP?

I see that there are modules for all three, which leads me to believe the answer to my question is none of them, but then what?

Comment: I sure would like to know why I lose points so often when I ask a question.  I see nothing wrong with my language or the format of the question.  can anyone help?

Comment: I would guess that you got downvotes here because your question shows very little evidence of you doing any research yourself ahead of time.  Any basic research would show that Express is a web server framework for node.js which, of course, means http and https.  A better question would show that you've done some research yourself on the question and then you got stuck on something and your question shows exactly where you got stuck.  I'd suggest you read [How do I ask a good question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to be a Google search service.  You should be asking things here that are not simple to find on your own with a few web searches.  So, the best questions show what research has already been done and explain exactly where you got confused in understanding what you found and are as specific as possible (not broad general questions).

Comment: I see that it might come across that way.  I did, in fact, research it for a while.  it's how I know that to do REST/SOAP/Json-RPC requires additional machinery, but nowhere was it clearly stated what protocol was used.  of course, now that I know the answer, it seems obvious.  Express is a web server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express is pretty much used for an HTTP server.  The protocol is HTTP.  Many of the features in Express are about HTTP routing and middleware to handle HTTP requests.

You can use HTTP requests to make a RESTful API.  You can use add-ons to Express to help you do that or you can certainly make a REST API in plain Express.  REST is not really a protocol so much as an architechural style and concept that can be implemented on different protocols (though in the web world, it usually uses HTTP).  Express routes match very well to REST endpoints so Express is well suited for implementing a REST API.

SOAP runs on top of HTTP (or can run on top of other protocols too).  You would probably want an add-on on top of Express to help with all the SOAP syntax that goes on top of HTTP because Express does not come with built-in support for SOAP.

There are flavors of RPC that can run on top of HTTP (there are other flavors that do not run on HTTP) and similarly, you would probably want an add-on to Express if you were going to do an HTTP-based RPC such as XML-RPC.  For a non-HTTP based RPC, you would probably not use Express.

Comment: thank you.  that was more informative than what I expected